# Convert Tableau function into Power Bi DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, tableau-api, powerbi-desktop

{FIXED[AUDIT] : MAX(if YEAR([SCHDL]) = year (today() )THEN [MIN_AUDIT] END }

I need to solve this Tableau sql into power BI DAX, can any one help me finding this

Comment: provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: I have added sample data for reference

Comment: I don't see any sample data at akk.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
=Calculate(MAX([MIN_Audit]),Year([SCHDL]) = Year(Today()))
```

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Then need to see more information on what result you expect and the nature of the data.